# Why does go build succeed for a regexp.MustCompile parsing error?

Tags: go, compiler-errors, go-build

It fails for `go run` or `go test` (compile then run), but not for `go build` (compile only). I would have thought `MustCompile` relates to compilation, not runtime.

---

```js
package main

import (
    "regexp"
)

var someInvalidRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`(?!`)

func main() {
    someInvalidRegex.MatchString("foo")
}
```

Runtime fail:

```
$ go run main.go
panic: regexp: Compile(`(?!`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`

goroutine 1 [running]:
regexp.MustCompile(0x10b7d19, 0x3, 0xc420022070)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/src/regexp/regexp.go:240 +0x171
exit status 2
```

Compilation success:

```
$ go build -o foo
$ echo $?
0
```

Runtime fail again:

```
$ ./foo
panic: regexp: Compile(`(?!`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`

goroutine 1 [running]:
regexp.MustCompile(0x10b7d19, 0x3, 0xc420022070)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec/src/regexp/regexp.go:240 +0x171
```

Comment: Regex compilation happens at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler does not analyze your regular expression. It is done in runtime.
"Compile" part of "MustCompile" function name stands for the compilation of the regular expression.